# How to set listview itemssource to a viewmodel in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, viewmodel

I'm trying to make a listview in xamarin show data from a restapi but have the option to filter the list or sort it based upon last name.

I've set the bindingcontext equal to the apiviewmodel which works. But I want to set the itemssource to a list which can be manipulated later instead of the binding context.

Here is the code that works:

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="DirectoryListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsList}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
```

Xaml.cs:

```
LocalAPIViewModel = new APIViewModel();
BindingContext = LocalAPIViewModel;
```

APIViewModel.cs:

```
private List<MainContacts> _ContactsList { get; set; }
public List<MainContacts> ContactsList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ContactsList;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != _ContactsList)
            {
                _ContactsList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

public class MainContacts
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

This all works fine. It's only when I add the following lines that it stops displaying the data in the listview:

xaml.cs:

```
LocalList = LocalAPIViewModel.ContactsList;
DirectoryListView.ItemsSource = LocalList;
```

I think I need to add these lines so that I can manipulate the list that's being displayed. Why is the list not being displayed? Is this not how it should be done?

Comment: Why do you want to add those lines? It completely violates the MVVM architechture. Furthermore, you are basically re-assigning the same data source to the ListView, that makes no sense. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As you can tell I'm very new to this. I want to be able to search the list with a search bar and also order it by first or last names. I also want to be able to click on one of the contacts and open up a separate page about that contact.

Comment: @Ryan,I do one sample that can meet your requirement, please take a look my reply update.

Comment: @Ryan, you don't need to add those lines, I use BindingContext to do sample that can accept your requirement, you can take a look my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and code, you use MVVM to bind ListView firstly, it works fine, now you want to use Viewmodel to  bind ListView itemsource in xaml.cs directly, am I right?

If yes,I do one sample according to your code, that you can take a look, the data can display successfully.

```
public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public APIViewModel LocalAPIViewModel { get; set; }
    public Page4 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        LocalAPIViewModel = new APIViewModel();           
        listview1.ItemsSource = LocalAPIViewModel.ContactsList;
    }
}

public class APIViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MainContacts> ContactsList { get; set; }
    public APIViewModel()
    {
        loadddata();
    }

    public void loadddata()
    {
        ContactsList = new ObservableCollection<MainContacts>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            MainContacts p = new MainContacts();
            p.ID = i;
            p.FirstName = "cherry"+i;
            ContactsList.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
public class MainContacts
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

so I suggest you can check ContactsList if has data.

**Update:**

> I want to be able to search the list with a search bar and also order it by first or last names. I also want to be able to click on one of the contacts and open up a separate page about that contact

I do one sample that can meet your requirement, you can take a look:

https://github.com/851265601/xf-listview

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please can you review my original question and if it's good then upvote it and if it's bad then let me know how I can improve it!

Answer (score 1):

*So, to answer all your questions...*

---

**First, the binding.**

Once you set the `ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsList}"` this means that anytime you signal that you have changed your `ContactsList` by calling `OnPropertyChanged()`, that is going to be reflected on the `ItemsSource` property (so, update the UI - that is why we put the `OnPropertyChanged()` into the setter). Thus, you do not need to manually set the `ItemsSource` every time you change it. (Especially from the View, as the View should have no knowledge of how the ContactsList is defined in the ViewModel.)

> So you can completely remove those lines from the View's code-behind.

---

**Next, the ordering and searching.**

What `OnPropertyChanged()` does, is that it re-requests the bound property from the ViewModel, and updates the View according to that. So, just after `OnPropertyChanged()` is called, the getter of the bound property (`ContactsList`) is called by the View.

So, a good idea is to put the sorting mechanism into the getter of the public property. (Or the setter, when resetting the property.) Something like this:

```
public class ViewModel {
    private ObserveableCollection<MainContacts> contactList { get; set; }
    public ObserveableCollection<MainContacts> ContactList {
        get {
            return new ObservableCollection<MainContacts>(contactList
                .Where(yourFilteringFunc)
                .OrderBy(yourOrderingFunc));
        }
        set {
            contactsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

So, whenever your public property is called, it will sort the private property and return the collection that way.

Comment: this really helped! Please can you look at my original question and, if it's good then upvote it and if it's bad then let me know how I can improve it!

Answer (score -1):

Change `public List<MainContacts> ContactsList` to `public ObservableCollection<MainContacts> ContactsList`

in **xaml.cs**

instead of `LocalList = LocalAPIViewModel.ContactsList;`, put

```
ContactsList = new ObservableCollection(LocalAPIViewModel.ContactsList);
```

I think this will work, instead of setting ListView's Itemsource to 'LocalList'

Comment: When adding this line to xaml.cs I get the following errors - ContactsList does not exist in the current context and ObservableCollection<T> requires 1 type arguments